# Confusig image.getNumChildren() not working properly /JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, loops, bitmap

I try to delete images from an array wehre I stored them. Only images that do not have childred get removed. But not every image that has no childres gets removed. I did a console.log in the for loop to see if the images that are not removed have children and they do not have... but they are still in the array. This is how I approached it:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.images_container.length;i++)
{
   if(this.images_container[i].getNumChildren() < 1)
   {
     console.log(this.images_contaier[i].getNumChildren());
     this.images_container.splice(i,1);

   }
     console.log(this.images_contaier[i].getNumChildren());                        
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you try to use: `.childElementCount` instead `.getNumChildren()`. take care `.childElementCount` is a number not a function. `this.images_container[i].childElementCount < 1`

Comment: an other note: `.childElementCount` count already the comment node `<!-- -->` like element.

Comment: @Frogmouth hi, thanks for the quick response! If I use childElementCount thank none of the images gets removed.

Comment: two thing:
1) can you post the HTML source? (maybe in http://jsfiddle.net/)
2) can you post the source code fo `childElementCount()`??
3) can you put a `console.log()` inside loop and log this: `console.log(this.images_contaier[i],this.images_contaier[i].childre)` and teel me the response. :)

Comment: @Frogmouth I have no html source because I am working with a framework.
this.images_container[i].children has the same result as getNumChildren()

Comment: @Frogmouth no I do not use any DOM elements

Comment: ... is too hard helping you without surce code... however... assuming that `this.images_contaier[i].children` = `this.images_contaier[i].getNumChildren()` try this: `this.images_container[i].children().length < 1` it seems inside the `this.images_container[i]` there are some children that aren't image. Like text Node or comment.

Comment: `console.log(this.images_contaier[i].getNumChildren());` log a number?

Comment: @Frogmouth in FireBug if I check the images under children property there is " children: Array[0]
So there should be no text Node. Am I right?

Comment: @Frogmout yes the log is a number

Comment: a number? a... dam. never log 0?

Comment: @Frogmouth oh sorry I mean it shows the right number of children. If there are no children then it shows 0

Comment: @Frogmouth I can get the right number of children for every image but in the in clause the images that return 0 children do not get deleted from the array. And I do not know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAIT. i see other problems:

1) `console.log(this.images_contaier[i].getNumChildren());` variables name in consolelog are wrong **contaier** is **container**.

2) not use `this.images_container.splice(i,1);` because i think it cause some issue. use an other new array to save the images_container with children:

```
var not_empty_container = [];
for(var i = 0; i < this.images_container.length;i++)
{
   if(this.images_container[i].getNumChildren() > 0)
   {
     console.log(this.images_container[i].getNumChildren());
     not_empty_container.push(this.images_contaier[i]);

   }
     console.log(this.images_container[i].getNumChildren());                        
}
this.images_contaier = not_empty_container;
console.log(this.images_contaier);
```

this works?

Comment: this works!! now I use another array to save the images that have children for this in the if clause I have to look after images with children.
thank you for helping me!

Comment: sorry?... no problem! ... :D it's normal. Glad to have helped. :)
yeee... eheh... I tried to find the problem where there problem was not... eheh... I must tell you i'm sorry, not you to me :D